# tinyxml2 : how to know number of characters read successfully from a stream buffer

Tags: c++, tinyxml2

I am using tinyxml2 interface to read xml data from stream buffer.

How can I know number of characters successfully read by tinyxml2 interface.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably this is what you are looking for.

According to [documentation](http://www.grinninglizard.com/tinyxmldocs/index.html) section "Printing" you can use `TiXmlPrinter` class to output to a `std::string` or memory buffer